# Unit Testing custom exception handler with IProblemDetailsService

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0

I have a simple minimal web API and have implemented custom error handling with the `UseExceptionHandler()` middleware, and want to use `IProblemDetailsService` to customize the response:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddProblemDetails();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseStatusCodePages();

app.UseExceptionHandler(exceptionHandlerApp =>
{
    exceptionHandlerApp.Run(async context =>
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/problem+json";
        if (context.RequestServices.GetService<IProblemDetailsService>() is { } problemDetailsService)
        {
            var exceptionHandlerFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
            var exceptionType = exceptionHandlerFeature?.Error;
            var problem = new ProblemDetailsContext
            {
                HttpContext = context,
                ProblemDetails =
                {
                    Title = "TestTitle",
                    Detail = "TestDetail",
                    Status = 123
                }
            };
            
            problem.ProblemDetails.Extensions.Add("exception", exceptionHandlerFeature?.Error.ToString());          
            
            await problemDetailsService.WriteAsync(problem);
            
        }
    });
});

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Controller:

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{   
    [HttpGet("{number}")]
    public IActionResult NumberEndpoint(int number)
    {
        if (number <= 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("yikes");
        }

        return Ok(number);
    }
}
```

This generally works. When I call the endpoint with a negative number with Swagger, I get my customized ProblemDetails object back.

Now I also want to write a test for that, which I can't get to work. The response body doesn't contain any content:

```cs
[Test]
public async Task ProblemDetailsTest()
{
    var application = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>();

    using var sut = application.CreateClient();
    var response = await sut.GetAsync($"/api/Values/NumberEndpoint/{-1}");

    // responseText is an empty string
    var responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        
}
```

What am I missing? I assume it has to be something in the test setup that I'm missing, but I can't find specifics regarding `IProblemDetailsService`, `UseExceptionHandler()` and tests

Comment: Did you debug it? Is your Controller even called? Is your ExceptionHandler called?

Comment: Yes, both the Controller and the exception handler are called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying with Integration test instead of Unit Test,also,a [minimal api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/overview?view=aspnetcore-7.0) won't have controllers

I tried to reproduced your issue and fixed it by add a Accept Header:

```
 _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/problem+json");
```

[image]